# How to invoke the Windows Search window from command-line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-search

The Windows 10 Taskbar has a Search command:

[image]

Clicking on this icon invokes the Windows Search window:

[image]

How can I invoke this Windows Search window from a command-line?

Comment: I misunderstood your request - Sorry.  I am not sure if you can even do start Search by command line. "Where" is the command line method.

Comment: The Windows Search window can also be invoked with the keyboard key combination `WIN+S`. So is there a  way to emulate the pressing of this keyboard key combination with a console command?

Comment: You can create a Windows Desktop Shortcut to *search-ms:* (include the trailing colon). See https://superuser.com/questions/1620107/how-to-invoke-the-windows-search-window-from-command-line . Then invoke the shortcut from CMD or Run.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for your advice. However, this command does not exactly invoke the Windows Search dialog from the screenshot above in my question. Instead, it opens Windows File Explorer with a focus on the file-search box. This means it searches only for FILES. It does not search for shortcuts in the Windows Start menu like the Windows Search dialog from my question.